# Upsert operation in SOAPUI to change the Account Name in salesforce

Tags: salesforce, soapui

How to create an upsert operation in SOAPUI inorder to change the Account name in salesforce.

Using the SOAPUI Tool I tried to write a connnection string  like UPDATE table name SET column name WHERE column name = SOme value

```
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:enterprise.soap.sforce.com">
    <soapenv:Header>
   <urn:SessionHeader>
   <urn:sessionId>00Do0000000K8o2!ARMAQPVLekBy0VKNXDIVHysA0Nn2FOAZKJBkixYVB6UnGgpz1oTSmAz2hwE41DhhB12Mf8Zi9wkKuDUHkLlXu84J7IsHrCLk</urn:sessionId>
   </urn:SessionHeader>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
   <urn:query>
      <urn:queryString>
 UPDATE Account SET Name ='Maddi' where Id ='001o000000RIrLhAAL' </urn:queryString>
      </urn:query>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Error is shown below

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:sf="urn:fault.enterprise.soap.sforce.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <soapenv:Fault>
         <faultcode>sf:MALFORMED_QUERY</faultcode>
         <faultstring>MALFORMED_QUERY: unexpected token: UPDATE</faultstring>
         <detail>
            <sf:MalformedQueryFault xsi:type="sf:MalformedQueryFault">
               <sf:exceptionCode>MALFORMED_QUERY</sf:exceptionCode>
               <sf:exceptionMessage>unexpected token: UPDATE</sf:exceptionMessage>
               <sf:row>1</sf:row>
               <sf:column>0</sf:column>
            </sf:MalformedQueryFault>
         </detail>
      </soapenv:Fault>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```